# What notification is sent when user tries power off the iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to know when a user press the power button to turn off the device. Is there any notification sent once the turn off condition is detected?

Comment: I don't think so, why?

Comment: I mean, is there any notifications in iOS(objective c/swift) like ACTION_SHUTDOWN intent broadcast in android

Comment: I don't think so, what do you want to use it for?

Comment: Do you need to know when your application because the phone goes to sleep mode or do you explicitly need a power button event?

Comment: Actually, I would like to present an alertview(to save the changes) in my application(running in background) when the user try to turn off the phone. So, is it possible to know that the phone is about to turn off?